# Legends not appearing in GeoServer Layer

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, legend, sld, xml

I have added a new style in GeoServer.

[image: Legend]

As I am seeing the preview of legend while creating the style, it is appearing.

But when I am applying the same to the GeoServer layer, it is not appearing in that.

[image: Layer]

How to make the legend appear on the layer?

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 10</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 10</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>10.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#440154</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>11 - 20</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>11 - 20</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>11.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>20.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#24868e</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>21 - 30</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>21 - 30</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>21.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>30.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#5dc962</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>31 - 40</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>31 - 40</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>31.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>40.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#8fd744</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>41 - 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>41 - 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>41.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e120</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>> 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>> 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e4e419</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I have added the add GetLegendGraphic request as per the official [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html)

Still legend not showing on the webpage

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=agrodss:Rainfall">
```

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Test AGRO DSS page - WMS GetFeatureInfo (Tile Layer) </title>
   
    <style>
        .map {
          width: 100%;
          height:600px;
        }
    </style>

     <!-- Import OpenLayers CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/agrodss_test/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/agrodss_test/libs/v6.4.3-dist/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=agrodss:Rainfall">



</head>

    <h1> GFS District Forecast </h1>
    <hr>

    <li>
         <a>Select by:</a> 
        <select id="filterType">
            <option value="state_name">State Name</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
        <a id="updateFilterButton" href="#" onClick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter">Apply</a>
        <a id="resetFilterButton" href="#" onClick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter">Reset</a>
    </li>
    
    
    <!-- to add javascript  -->
    <div id= 'js-map' class='map' ></div>
    <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <span id="status"></span>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/agrodss_test/get_map_info.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/agrodss_test/libs/v6.4.3-dist/ol.js"></script>
    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you request the legend anywhere in your code? Or as a decoration to your map? Have you looked in the manual?

Comment: Yes @Ian Turton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean display categorized colors on `WMS` layer for each interval, you need `<Add>` tag that acts as `&&` operator.
For example, if rainfall falls between 10-30, you can implement it as follow:

```xml
<Filter>
  <And>
    <PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      <PropertyName>rainfall</PropertyName>
      <Literal>10</Literal>
    </PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
    <PropertyIsLessThan>
      <PropertyName>rainfall</PropertyName>
      <Literal>30</Literal>
    </PropertyIsLessThan>
  </And>
</Filter>
```

which means `rainfall >= 10 && rainfall < 30`. A full guide is found [here](https://geoserver-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styling/sld-reference/filters.html).

For displaying legend on map like what you see in style manager, you need to send request to geoserver based on [official document](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html).